# Azure Key Vault Secrets Query

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I had a couple of questions around Azure Key Vault where I needed some technical assistance:
The link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview states that *"Secrets and keys are safeguarded by Azure, using industry-standard algorithms, key lengths, and hardware security modules (HSMs). The HSMs used are Federal Information Processing Standards (FIPS) 140-2 Level 2 validated"*.

I wanted to confirm whether this was true for secrets as much as they were true for keys. The reason for this is secrets have to leave the HSM and be transferred to the end application which needs to use them.

The second was around the size of the secrets itself. I have seen conflicting information on secrets size which state its either 10 KB and 25 KB max size per secret. What is the best way to validate this?

Any help that you can provide would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: While I too have seen conflicting info about secret size over time, the current official docs say 25K, so I would tend to go with that.  If you need absolute assurance, test it with something larger than 10K or contact MS for confirmation.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/about-secrets

Answer (score 1):

Secrets itself are protected by HSM by being encrypted by HSM keys (Encryption at Rest) - I hope this helps.

25k is max size per secrets.

Comment: Just wanted to note that Jack is on the Key Vault team.